# How can I keep my animation in Orthographic when doing a final animation?

Tags: animation, orthographic

I've rendered all of my images in Orthographic PNG and have them synced up to a song,

[image]

but now all of my square orthographic images are being stretched to 1920 x 1080 when I load them to my video sequence editor.

[image]

Clicking the "Image Offset" button will make them square/orthographic once again, but I'm worried that this is reducing the picture to a thumbnail size (not to mention reducing the quality as well).

[image]

I've looked through the forums and read the blender manual on animating and Ortho-Cameras but can't seem to find anything detailing the Orthographic image mode when finalizing an animation.

Here's my render settings:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. :) cheers.

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of the render settings you use please?

Comment: Ok, hopefully that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out thanks to @Hendriks3D's question.

My Original render settings are set above, but when opening a new window and loading my images, the camera render settings were moved back to 1920 x 1080 which changes the rendered images regardless of original render size.

I just changed them to my 1080 x 1000 and Tadaa!!! it's all correctly shaped again. Thanks @Hendriks3D for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Haha, no problem.